# Custom navigation bar items improperly placed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a custom navigation bar subclass:

```
class ProfileNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

  var titleLabel: UILabel
  var backButton: UIBarButtonItem
  var friendsButton: FriendsButton?

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 320, height: 40))
    backButton = UIBarButtonItem.backButton(nil, action: nil)
    friendsButton = FriendsButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let item = UINavigationItem()
    item.titleView = titleLabel

    item.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    item.hidesBackButton = true

    let friendsItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: friendsButton!)
    item.rightBarButtonItems = [friendsItem]

    pushItem(item, animated: false)
  }

}
```

where the FriendsButton resizes itself when it's state property is changed.

Problem is that when the view is first loaded, it appears like this, with the back button and the FriendsButton right at the edge of the nav bar: (`.loading` state)

[image]

However, when I change the FriendsButton state to `.add`, it appears normally like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Here is the implementation of FriendsButton:

```
class FriendsButton: UIView {

  var state: FriendsButtonState {
    didSet {
      style(selected: state)
    }
  }

  var title: String = "" {
    didSet {
      set(title: title)
    }
  }

  var font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)

  private var imageView: UIImageView!
  private var button: UIButton!
  var loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!

  init(frame: CGRect, state: FriendsButtonState = .loading) {
    self.state = state
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .yellow

    let plusSize = frame.size.height/2
    let plusYValue = (frame.size.height-plusSize)/2
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: plusYValue*2, y: plusYValue, width: plusSize, height: plusSize))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    addSubview(imageView)

    let titleSize = (title as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: plusYValue*3.5 + plusSize, y: 0, width: titleSize.width, height: frame.size.height))
    addSubview(button)

    loading = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    loading.center = center
    addSubview(loading)

    style(selected: state)

    updateSize()
  }

  func addTarget(object: Any, selector: Selector) {
    button.addTarget(object, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  private func style(selected: FriendsButtonState) {
    configureBorder(state: selected)
    loading.startAnimating()
    loading.isHidden = state != .loading
    isHidden = false

    switch state {
    case .friends:
      backgroundColor = .black
      button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
      imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "friends-tick")
      title = "Friends"
    // ... + all other cases
    }
    self.updateSize()
  }

  private func configureBorder(state: FriendsButtonState) {
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = state == .loading ? 0 : 1
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
  }

  private func set(title: String) {
    let plusSize = frame.size.height/2
    let plusYValue = (frame.size.height-plusSize)/2
    let titleSize = (title as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
    button.titleLabel?.font = font
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: plusYValue*3.5 + plusSize, y: 0, width: titleSize.width, height: frame.size.height)
    self.updateSize()
  }

  private func updateSize() {
    if state == .loading {
      frame.size.width = frame.size.width
      loading.center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)
      loading.startAnimating()
      return
    }

    let plusSize = frame.size.height/2
    let plusYValue = (frame.size.height-plusSize)/2
    let titleSize = (title as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
    let totalWidth = plusYValue*5.5 + plusSize + titleSize.width
    frame.size.width = totalWidth
  }
```

**EDIT:** I have tried setting the button to the `.add` state initially but it would still appear at the very right of the nav bar until it was changed to the other state. It seems that the first state of the button always make the nav bar to shift all its children to the edge of the frame until it is updated.

**EDIT:** I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on another project by copying the relevant code, but this is the specific problem I am having (shown in the image below). The gap between the edge of the navigation bar and the back button is not maintained when first navigating to the view (I managed to get a screenshot midway through the navigation push animation). My question is now, what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: can you show us how you implemented this `FriendsButton` ?

Comment: just added it as an edit @tgyhlsb

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to **stop** the activity indicator, otherwise it won't hide itself:

```
private func style(selected: FriendsButtonState) {
    configureBorder(state: selected)
    if (state == .loading) {
        loading.startAnimating()
    } else {
        loading.stopAnimating()
    }
    loading.isHidden = state != .loading
```

Btw: You could also skip `loading.isHidden = state != .loading` if you configure the `UIActivityIndicatorView` as to hide itself when its stopped:

```
init(frame: CGRect, state: FriendsButtonState = .loading) {
     // ...

    loading = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    loading.center = center
    loading.hidesWhenStopped = true
    addSubview(loading)
    // ...
}
```

To **lay out the right navigation bar button** correctly, you have to modify `FriendsButton.updateSize`: When in state `.loading` - at least for the first time - you also have to update the frame.

```
private func updateSize() {
    if state == .loading {
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width
        loading.center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)
        loading.startAnimating()
        // do not return here
    }

    let plusSize = frame.size.height/2
    let plusYValue = (frame.size.height-plusSize)/2
    let titleSize = (title as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
    let totalWidth = plusYValue*5.5 + plusSize + titleSize.width
    frame.size.width = totalWidth
}
```

I assume the same for the left button, but unfortunalty the your code does not compile here (get an error in the init? method when calling `backButton = UIBarButtonItem.backButton(nil, action: nil)`, because there is no static member backButton on `UIBarButtonItem`

---

Now, [it works on my machine](http://briceno.mx/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/keep-calm-it-works-on-my-machine.png):

Just after start of the app:
[image: Just after start of the app]

After state change to .friends
[image: After state change to .friends]

State changed back again to .loading
[image: State changed back again to .loading]

Everything is well aligned, no changes etc.
If this does not hold true for your project, than there might be other aspects that you didn't publish with your code.

Comment: Thanks, this helped but is not the answer to the question... the nav bar items will still appear with no spacing at the left and right edges initially.

Comment: Added information about the right button (cannot compile code belonging to left button, see above, therefor no info about it)

Comment: The problem is not with the FriendsButton button or the back button but with the navigation bar. The items inside the FriendsButton and the back button and titleView all appear correctly however their positioning inside the navigation bar is incorrect... the standard inset from the left of the screen to the back button and the inset from the right of the screen to the FriendsButton is not appearing when the views are first initialised. However when the state of the FriendsButton is changed, the views adjust themselves and this inset is fixed and everything appears perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. It would help if you could somehow upload a small project which is compilable and shows the effect, as well as an image with arrows indicating your problem. From my point of view (regarding the  FriendsButton) my solution seems quite OK; I cannot see any misalignment (expecially between "initial" state and after the state has changed)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on another project, but please look at my modified question for a more clear representation of what the problem is. Obviously it is not to with the ProfileNavigationBar or the FriendsButton. Do you know what else might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: @jacobsieradzki It's a little frustrating if you post code that cannot reproduce your problem. Without the relevant code it would only be guessing.

Answer (score 3):

You should update the frames of the subviews in `layoutSubviews()`, so you should override this method. The layoutSubviews() method is called whenever the frame changes and when the layout is flagged as being 'dirty' (by calling `setNeedsLayout()` you can achieve this).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to set the FriendsButtonState of the friendsButton in the init. Change:

```
friendsButton = FriendsButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
```

to

```
friendsButton = FriendsButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24), state:.add)
```

Comment: I tried this but it still had the same effect where the 'add' version of the button would appear at the very right of the nav bar. Anyway, I need the button to be loading until the relationship is loaded..